# Case insensitive search inside projection condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

The data in hotel table is stored like

```
   {
     _id: ....,
     HotelName: ...,
     MasterKeyDetails:[
     { 
       MasterKeyId: 36K1,
       ...
     },
     {
        MasterKeyId: 36J1,
       ...
     }
     ]

  }
```

I have written below query

```
       $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate(array(
                array(
                    '$match' => array(
                        "_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    '$project' => array(
                        'MasterKeyDetails' => array(
                            '$filter' => array(
                                'input' => '$MasterKeyDetails',
                                'as' => 'room',
                                'cond' => array(
                                    '$eq' => array('$$room.MasterKeyId', $this->MasterKeyId)
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                    )
                )
            )
         )->toArray();
```

It is searching fine. It searches when $this->MasterKeyId contains 36K1, but does not search when $this->MasterKeyId contains 36k1. I want it should fetch despite of case sensitive data...

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$toUpper`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) to normalise the data:

```
   $cursor = $this->collection->aggregate(array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    "_id" => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->id)
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'MasterKeyDetails' => array(
                        '$filter' => array(
                            'input' => '$MasterKeyDetails',
                            'as' => 'room',
                            'cond' => array(
                                '$eq' => array(array('$toUpper' =>'$$room.MasterKeyId'), $this->MasterKeyId)
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
     )->toArray();
```

In the same way you make sure the data you have to supply for comparison is also in the same case. There is also [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) if you prefer that way.

As yet there is no other "case insensitive match" function you can use as part of an aggregation pipeline, so "normalizing" is the current approach.